# I've trying to install Sitecore, getting error: Missing source parameter

Tags: azure, installation

I am trying to install Sitecore 9 update 2 on Azure.  I am getting this error:

> Package deployment failed ARM-MSDeploy Deploy Failed:
> 'Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentClientServerException: Missing
> source parameter 'Search Provider' (Sitecore Search Provider). This
> must be set for successful synchronization

In the nested/application.json it has the following var/param defined.

```
"variables": {
              "searchProvider": "[if(empty(parameters('solrConnectionString')), 'azure', 'solr')]",
              ...
```

below that section has:

```
"setParameters": {
              "Search Provider": "[variables('searchProvider')]",
              ...
```

I found that someone had an answer for this type of issue for a previous version of Sitecore 8.2.  In the Deployment Scripts section on this page: https://github.com/HedgehogDevelopment/AzureDeployTemplates/blob/master/Blog%20Posts.md  But it doesn't look like my version 9.0.2 has the same file structure.

They said they got the fix from Bas Lijten but when I went to his contact page http://blog.baslijten.com/contact it's broken.  :)  (Murphy's Law)

So if anyone can offer any help I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are going to use Solr for Sitecore, you have to pass a value to `solrConnectionString` property from `azuredeploy.parameters.json` file.

Add a new entry into the parameters json file, then pass your `SolrConnectionString` value from the Powershell script by adding it into the Parameters variable.

```
"solrConnectionString": {
      "value": ""
}
```